# Finding a surface area with critical points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given an area $A(x,y)$ and the associated critical points $x$ and $y,$ are there are any ways to determine the area of the given function?

A volume of a rectangular container measures $V=\alpha=xyz$.

$A=2\left ( xy+xz+yz \right )$

In terms of x,y: $A\left ( x,y \right )=2\left ( xy+\frac{\alpha}{y} +\frac{\alpha}{z}\right )$ where $\alpha$ is a constant.

The gradient of A:

$\vec{\bigtriangledown }A\left ( x,y \right )=2\left \langle y-\frac{\alpha}{x^{2}},x-\frac{\alpha}{y^{2}} \right \rangle$

The Jacobian of A:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{4\alpha}{x^{3}} & 2\\ 
2&\frac{4\alpha}{y^{3}} 
\end{bmatrix}$

The critical points of A:

$A_{x}=0,a_{y}=0$

$x=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\sqrt{y}}$

$y=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\sqrt{x}}$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your Jacobian is wrong, how did you calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand at all what you did after the gradient. Here is my attempt:

$$ \vec{\nabla} A = \left ( y - \frac{\alpha}{x^2} , x - \frac{\alpha}{y^2} \right ) = (0,0)$$

So

$$y - \frac{\alpha}{x^2}=0 \ , \ x-\frac{\alpha}{y^2}=0 $$
$$ x^2 y = \alpha \ , \ xy^2 = \alpha \ \ \ (*)$$

From here we conclude that

$$ x^2 y= xy^2 $$

If $\alpha = xyz \neq 0$ then $x,y \neq 0$ and we can divide the equation above by $xy$ and get

$$ x = y$$

Substituting that in $(*)$ we get

$$x^3=y^3=\alpha \Rightarrow x=y=z=\sqrt[3]{\alpha}$$

Meaning you minimize the surface area of the box when it is a cube.

You could also solve this problem using Lagrange's multipliers, if you heard of the concept.